# How to convert pandas series to 2D array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas series that looks like this:[image]

How can I convert this into a 2D array that looks like this: ([10.32.5.53, 1008],[10.32.5.56,1002]...[10.32.5.58,11]) ?

Comment: `s.to_frame().reset_index().values`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my edits are removed from @RikKraan post, here the answer as I mentioned in the comments to his reply.

First apply `reset_index` to your series and then use `to_numpy`, i.e.

```
series.reset_index().to_numpy()
```

Note, `reset_index` converts the series to a dataframe.

As mentioned in the comments, the OP wants to store the IP as float.
This can be done by removing the `.` in the IP string and converting the index to `float` before converting as mentioned above. I.e.

```
series.index = series.index.str.replace('.','').astype(float)
series.reset_index().to_numpy()
```

This will give you your 2D numpy array with dtype float.

Comment: Okay thank you this works, but it made the IP values into strings :[['10.32.5.54' 1008]['10.32.5.56' 1002] ['10.32.5.53' 966]...], I need to have an array of type float

Comment: @super95 How do you want to store the IPs as float? `'10.32.5.54'` as `1032554.0`?

Comment: Yes I want to store it like that